# PHPExcel row/field custom metadata?

Tags: php, xml, excel, metadata, openxml

I use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to export data from mysql and `$workbook->getProperties()->setCustomProperty()` to store table name.

But i'd also like to store an *primary_key* field for importing without having visible column for it.
And it should stick to the row so editors can delete rows.

PHPExcel is lacking of documentation so i didn't find anything at the moment.

Is it even possible? Haven't digged into `OfficeOpenXML` docs yet - looking for existing solution.

Cheers!

Comment: PHPExcel is lacking of documentation ?!? - don't know why I bother

Comment: Incidentally, custom properties aren't stored against the sheet, they're stored against the workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not store the primary key in column A of your worksheet, and then set column A to "hidden"?

You can find out how to do this by reading section 4.6.29. in the (non-existent) Developer Documentation, entitled "Show/hide a column"